# Upsert with incrementing a value if the row exists

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection "servers" that looks like:

```
{"server": "234.234.34.34", "count": 1}
```

I want make this call, and if the row exists I want to just update the counter, otherwise insert with the value 'count' 1.

Is this possible?

I know you can upsert, but not sure how to handle an update with an increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
db.getCollection('server').update(
    {"server": "234.234.34.34"},
    { $inc: { count: 1 } },
    {upsert: true}
)
```